# Displaying an iterative menu in JAVA

Tags: java, css, menu

I have written the following code in the main function of my program to generate a menu driven program. There are basically six options available on the Menu and the `menu()` not only displays the menu but also returns the user's choice. If you require the code for that, I'll post it.

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{   BufferedReader bw=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    attendance_and_student_management object=new attendance_and_student_management();
    int flag=1;
    while(flag==1)
    {   int var=object.menu();
         if(var==1)
         {  System.out.println("\f");
            object.add_student();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Would you like to return to the Main Menu to perform more tasks? Press 1 for Yes and 0 for No");
            flag=Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());
            }
         else if(var==2)
         {  System.out.println("\f");
            object.search_student();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Would you like to return to the Main Menu to perform more tasks? Press 1 for Yes and 0 for No");
            flag=Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());
            }
         else if(var==3)
         {   System.out.println("\f");
            object.change_student_information();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Would you like to return to the Main Menu to perform more tasks? Press 1 for Yes and 0 for No");
            flag=Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());;
        }
         else if(var==4)
         { System.out.println("\f");
            object.take_attendance();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Would you like to return to the Main Menu to perform more tasks? Press 1 for Yes and 0 for No");
           flag=Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());;
            }
         else if(var==5)
         {   System.out.println("\f");
            object.attendance_summary();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Would you like to return to the Main Menu to perform more tasks? Press 1 for Yes and 0 for No");
            flag=Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());;
            }
         else if(var==6)
         {
            System.out.println("\f");
            object.monthly_defaulter_list();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Would you like to return to the Main Menu to perform more tasks? Press 1 for Yes and 0 for No");
            flag=Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());;
            }
          else if(var==7)
          { System.out.println("\f");
            System.out.println("THANK YOU FOR USING THE PROGRAM!!");
            System.exit(0);
            }
          else
          { System.out.println("\f");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Invalid Input. Would you like to try again? Press 1 for Yes");
            int chhh=Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());
            if(chhh==1)
            { flag=1;
            }
            else 
            { flag=0;
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I am facing only one issue with this code, it goes to a particular method and remains stuck on that method forever. So for instance, I want to add a student. On the menu, I choose 1 and since var==1 is true, the method add_student is called. Once I am done adding a student, I AM NOT ABLE to come back to the menu. What I mean by this is that the line 
`System.out.println("Would you like to return to the Main Menu to perform more tasks.....");` is not executed. What is the Flaw?

My goal is to first display the menu through the menu function, then ask the user if he/she wants to perform any more tasks. If he/she wants to, then by pressing 'Y' the menu should get displayed again and so on. If after any iteration the user wants to quit then he/she should either choose 7 as an option to quit or simply enter 'N' or any other valid character.

PS: This is my new attempt at the code, I decided to change the switch statement as I do not fully understand it.

Comment: do u have some error?

Comment: You do not `break` from the default section. That break is breaking you out of the loop, hence why it is stopping immediately regardless. We need to know what the `attendance_and_student_management` class does to figure out the first issue.